# From a technical standpoint, how does the zero-day Internet Explorer vulnerability discovered in September 2012 work?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, malware, known-vulnerabilities

I'm looking for an answer that explains the issue from the prespective of a developer/engineer. What is exactly being exploited and why does it work?

Please note that I am *not* looking for instructions on how to exploit nor I am interested in reproducing it in any way; I'm merely curious about the technical background behind it.

Some Relevant Links:

[Microsoft Security Advisory 2757760](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2757760)
[CVE-20012-4969 on MITRE](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-4969)
[CVE-20012-4969 on NVD](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-4969)
[CVE-20012-4969 on CVE Details](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-4969/)

Comment: Seems like a buffer overflow.

Comment: It's not a buffer overflow, it's a use-after-free.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[CVE-2012-4969](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-4969), aka the latest IE 0-day, is a based on a use-after-free bug in IE's rendering engine. A use-after-free occurs when a dynamically allocated block of memory is used after it has been disposed of (i.e. freed). Such a bug can be exploited by creating a situation where an internal structure contains pointers to sensitive memory locations (e.g. the stack or executable heap blocks) in a way that causes the program to copy shellcode into an executable area.

In this case, the problem is with the `CMshtmlEd::Exec` function in `mshtml.dll`. The `CMshtmlEd` object is freed unexpectedly, then the `Exec` method is called on it *after* the free operation.

First, I'd like to cover some theory. If you already know how use-after-free works, then feel free to skip ahead.

At a low level, a class can be equated to a memory region that contains its state (e.g. fields, properties, internal variables, etc) and a set of functions that operate on it. The functions actually take a "hidden" parameter, which points to the memory region that contains the instance state.

For example (excuse my *terrible* pseudo-C++):

```
class Account
{
    int balance = 0;
    int transactionCount = 0;

    void Account::AddBalance(int amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
        transactionCount++;
    }

    void Account::SubtractBalance(int amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
        transactionCount++;
    }
}
```

The above can actually be represented as the following:

```
private struct Account
{
    int balance = 0;
    int transactionCount = 0;
}

public void* Account_Create()
{
    Account* account = (Account*)malloc(sizeof(Account));
    account->balance = 0;
    account->transactionCount = 0;
    return (void*)account;
}

public void Account_Destroy(void* instance)
{
    free(instance);
}

public void Account_AddBalance(void* instance, int amount)
{
    ((Account*)instance)->balance += amount;
    ((Account*)Account)->transactionCount++;
}

public void Account_SubtractBalance(void* instance, int amount)
{
    ((Account*)instance)->balance -= amount;
    ((Account*)instance)->transactionCount++;
}

public int Account_GetBalance(void* instance)
{
    return ((Account*)instance)->balance;
}

public int Account_GetTransactionCount(void* instance)
{
    return ((Account*)instance)->transactionCount;
}
```

I'm using `void*` to demonstrate the opaque nature of the reference, but that's not really important. The point is that we don't want anyone to be able to alter the `Account` struct manually, otherwise they could add money arbitrarily, or modify the balance without increasing the transaction counter.

Now, imagine we do something like this:

```
void* myAccount = Account_Create();
Account_AddBalance(myAccount, 100);
Account_SubtractBalance(myAccount, 75);
// ...
Account_Destroy(myAccount);
// ...
if(Account_GetBalance(myAccount) > 1000) // <-- !!! use after free !!!
    ApproveLoan();
```

Now, by the time we reach `Account_GetBalance`, the pointer value in `myAccount` actually points to memory that is in an indeterminate state. Now, imagine we can do the following:

1. Trigger the call to `Account_Destroy` reliably.
2. Execute any operation *after* `Account_Destroy` but *before* `Account_GetBalance` that allows us to allocate a reasonable amount of memory, with contents of our choosing.

Usually, these calls are triggered in different places, so it's not too difficult to achieve this. Now, here's what happens:

1. `Account_Create` allocates an 8-byte block of memory (4 bytes for each field) and returns a pointer to it. This pointer is now stored in the `myAccount` variable.
2. `Account_Destroy` frees the memory. The `myAccount` variable still points to the same memory address.
3. We trigger our memory allocation, containing repeating blocks of `39 05 00 00 01 00 00 00`. This pattern correlates to `balance = 1337` and `transactionCount = 1`. Since the old memory block is now marked as free, it is very likely that the memory manager will write our new memory over the old memory block.
4. `Account_GetBalance` is called, expecting to point to an `Account` struct. In actuality, it points to our overwritten memory block, resulting in our balance actually being 1337, so the loan is approved!

This is all a simplification, of course, and real classes create rather more obtuse and complex code. The point is that a class instance is really just a pointer to a block of data, and class methods are just the same as any other function, but they "silently" accept a pointer to the instance as a parameter.

This principle can be extended to control values on the stack, which in turn causes program execution to be modified. Usually, the goal is to drop shellcode on the stack, then overwrite a return address such that it now points to a `jmp esp` instruction, which then runs the shellcode.

This trick works on non-DEP machines, but when DEP is enabled it prevents execution of the stack. Instead, the shellcode must be designed using [Return-Oriented Programming (ROP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming), which uses small blocks of legitimate code from the application and its modules to perform an API call, in order to bypass DEP.

Anyway, I'm going off-topic a bit, so let's get into the juicy details of CVE-2012-4969!

In the wild, the payload was dropped via a [packed Flash file](http://eromang.zataz.com/2012/09/16/zero-day-season-is-really-not-over-yet/), designed to exploit the Java vulnerability and the new IE bug in one go. There's also been some interesting [analysis of it by AlienVault](http://labs.alienvault.com/labs/index.php/2012/new-internet-explorer-zero-day-being-exploited-in-the-wild/).

The [metasploit module](http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/repository/entry/modules/exploits/windows/browser/ie_execcommand_uaf.rb) says the following:

> This module exploits a vulnerability found in Microsoft Internet Explorer (MSIE). When rendering an HTML page, the CMshtmlEd object gets deleted in an unexpected manner, but the same memory is reused again later in the CMshtmlEd::Exec() function, leading to a use-after-free condition.

There's also an interesting [blog post](http://blog.vulnhunt.com/index.php/2012/09/17/ie-execcommand-fuction-use-after-free-vulnerability-0day_en/) about the bug, albeit in rather poor English - I believe the author is Chinese. Anyway, the blog post goes into some detail:

> When the `execCommand` function of IE execute a command event, will allocated the corresponding `CMshtmlEd` object by `AddCommandTarget` function, and then call `mshtml@CMshtmlEd::Exec()` function execution. But, after the `execCommand` function to add the corresponding event, will immediately trigger and call the corresponding event function. Through the `document.write("L")` function to rewrite html in the corresponding event function be called. Thereby lead IE call `CHTMLEditor::DeleteCommandTarget` to release the original applied object of `CMshtmlEd`, and then cause triggered the used-after-free vulnerability when behind execute the `msheml!CMshtmlEd::Exec()` function.

Let's see if we can parse that into something a little more readable:

1. An event is applied to an element in the document.
2. The event executes, via `execCommand`, which allocates a `CMshtmlEd` object via the `AddCommandTarget` function.
3. The target event uses `document.write` to modify the page.
4. The event is no longer needed, so the `CMshtmlEd` object is freed via `CHTMLEditor::DeleteCommandTarget`.
5. `execCommand` later calls `CMshtmlEd::Exec()` on that object, *after* it has been freed.

Part of the code at the crash site looks like this:

```
637d464e 8b07            mov     eax,dword ptr [edi]
637d4650 57              push    edi
637d4651 ff5008          call    dword ptr [eax+8]
```

The use-after-free allows the attacker to control the value of `edi`, which can be modified to point at memory that the attacker controls. Let's say that we can insert arbitrary code into memory at `01234f00`, via a memory allocation. We populate the data as follows:

```
01234f00:    01234f08
01234f04:    41414141
01234f08:    01234f0a
01234f0a:    cccccccc // int3 breakpoint
```

1. We set `edi` to `01234f00`, via the use-after-free bug.
2. `mov eax,dword ptr [edi]` results in `eax` being populated with the memory at the address in `edi`, i.e. `01234f00`.
3. `push edi` pushes `01234f00` to the stack.
4. `call dword ptr [eax+8]` takes `eax` (which is `01234f00`) and adds 8 to it, giving us `01234f08`. It then dereferences that memory address, giving us `01234f0a`. Finally, it calls `01234f0a`.
5. The data at `01234f0a` is treated as an instruction. `cc` translates to an `int3`, which causes the debugger to raise a breakpoint. We've executed code!

This allows us to control `eip`, so we can modify program flow to our own shellcode, or to a ROP chain.

Please keep in mind that the above is *just an example*, and in reality there are many other challenges in exploiting this bug. It's a pretty standard use-after-free, but the nature of JavaScript makes for some interesting timing and heap-spraying tricks, and DEP forces us to use ROP to gain an executable memory block.

Anyway, this was fun to research, and I hope it helps.

Comment: Great answer! one thing missing is how exactly does the memory related to the event get overwritten between `DeleteCommandTarget` and `Exec`, which apparently is done through Javascript, this article has a good summary on that part: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/19/zero_day_ie/

Comment: @Mahn - That would be in the answer to the question "how would one exploit the vulnerability?"... not how does the flaw work.

Comment: @Chad nevermind to what I wrote before, I see your point.

Comment: The real question is *HOW* this vuln was discovered, not the details of the vuln.

Comment: @WindChaser Looking at the details, seems like VulnHunt found it, probably via fuzzing.

Answer (score 2):

It you look at the technet article you'll see a reference to [CVE-2012-4969](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-4969). The CVE page has several references, the most helpful of which (IMHO) is [this one](http://blog.vulnhunt.com/index.php/2012/09/17/ie-execcommand-fuction-use-after-free-vulnerability-0day_en/). The English isn't great, but it's readable.

Also see [El Reg](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/19/zero_day_ie/) for a more plain language explanation.

I'm not going to post an enormous explanation here as it would simply be ripping off other people's work, but to summarize it's a coding error around the treatment of dead objects that results in arbitrary code execution.

Comment: While this has some useful links, there's no actual content here to provide a proper answer.